# Yii2 RBAC allow backend access only to admin

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, rbac

My question is similar to this https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/rbac-restrict-backend-site/82416

I've tried to make it work with following code but it doesn't work. I've yii2 advanced, I've done migrations. How to make it work?

Roles: Administrator, User

Permission: canAccessBackend

Users: admin

Assignment: admin is assigned Roles Administrator and Permission canAccessBackend

/backend/controllers/SiteController.php

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (Yii::$app->user->can("canAccessBackend")) { 
    } 
    else {
        throw new ForbiddenHttpException("You do not have permission to access this page.");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Another code as per suggestions in comment. It still doesn't work.

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (Yii::$app->user->can("canAccessBackend")) { 
        return true;
    } 
    throw new ForbiddenHttpException("You do not have permission to access this page.");
}
```

**SiteController.php**

```
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\LoginForm;

/**
 * Site controller
 */
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                        [
                            'allow' => true,
                            'roles' => ['canAccessBackend'], //add only admin allowed
                        ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    /**
     * Login action.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        $this->layout = 'login';

        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            $model->password = '';

            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logout action.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }
}
```

**/common/config/main.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',

    'modules' => [
        'admin' => [
            'class' => 'mdm\admin\Module',
        ]
    ],

    'components' => [

        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],

        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager', // or use 'yii\rbac\PhpManager'
            'defaultRoles' => ['admin', 'guest'],
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'mdm\admin\models\User',
            'loginUrl' => ['admin/user/login'],
        ],

    ],
];
```

Comment: remove the `else` part and just add `ForbiddenHttpException` as the last line and then move the `return true` inside the `if(Yii::$app->user->can("canAccessBackend"))`

Comment: Tx for reply. It throws error when I logout - Class 'backend\controllers\ForbiddenHttpException' not found. I've updated my question with code.

Comment: add `use yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException` on top or use with full namespace `throw new \yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException("your message.")`

Comment: and you should move the `ForbiddenHttpException` out of the `if` block it should be outside `if` as the last line of the `beforeAction` reead my comment carefully

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I've tried but it still doesn't work. I've updated code.

Comment: doesnt work wont help much, have you created roles, assigned roles to the user in auth_assignment,

Comment: I've already created all those stuff as mentioned at the top of my question. I can see db tables and entries.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AccessFilter for this:
top:

```
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
```

in controller:

```
    /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function behaviors()
        {
            return [
                'access' => [
                    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                    'only' => ['login', 'logout', 'index'],
                    'rules' => [
                         [
                              'allow' => true,
                              'actions' => ['login'],
                              'roles' => ['?'],
                        ],
                        [
                            'allow' => true,
                            'actions' => ['index', 'logout'],
                            'roles' => ['canAccessBackend'], //add only admin allowed
                        ],
                    ],
//                  Use this property to throw any message or set flash message 
                    //'denyCallback'  => function ($rule, $action) {
                    //   \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'This section is only for registered users.');
                    //   \Yii::$app->user->loginRequired();
                ],
            ];
        }
```

Also add this in main.conf components to separate sessions from frontend:

```
'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the backend
            'name' => 'advanced-backend',
        ],
```

Hope it will helps.

Comment: I already have AccessFilter, I've tried with many access classes and rules. none of them are working. In your code 'roles' => ['canAccessBackend'], is incorrect. canAccessBackend is permission and not role. role is admin.

Comment: You are not right: _roleParams: specifies the parameters that will be passed to yii\web\User::can(). See the section below describing RBAC rules to see how it can be used. If this option is empty or not set, then no parameters will be passed._ That is from official documentation, And code i posted is from real project that works like expected.

Comment: I've just started learning so can't understand any deep stuff. I've updated my question with my SiteController.php & config/main.php files. Please have a look and let me know what I need to do to get admin restricted to admin users only?

Comment: Also remove `beforeAction` method, you do not need this

Comment: I've already tried the rules which you have mentioned. It still doesn't work. With your solution when I click on Logout it goes to backend/web/ after that I'm not sure if logout has been executed or not but I can still access all backend urls. With all these fixing it seems I've missed something somewhere. How to debug? Where to check?

Comment: If you can access urls after `logout`, that means that session still alive. Show what `logout` method does. i mean this `Yii::$app->user->logout();`